# Why do I have blurred vision and how do I fix it?

Tags: fallout-4

I've come across a really annoying visual effect in Fallout 4. It appeared as the vision was green, and the closer to the edges, the more distorted it got. Also, looking through the rifle's sight caused too much light, so much that I couldn't see anything.

At first, I thought it was addiction to chems, so I looked for some [addictol](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Addictol), but using it didn't help.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some time spent on looking how to solve this I came across the solution [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164594-fallout-4/72808267?page=1). This is a night vision glitch and you can get rid of it following way:

**Open the console and type in: `rimod 00094636`**

Hope this will help other players stuck on this issue.

Comment: do you have any info on how to fix it on consoles?

Comment: @RobertWertz unfortunately the only way is to revert to a save before the bug happened.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer If you read the linked thread, it's a glitch in the game's system for switching image modes (to night vision, or the recon scope vision mode, and possibly other visual effect modes). The game doesn't exit the vision mode when it should. You may be able to get it to trigger the vision mode exit call by entering and exiting the vision modes normally - I had this issue when I entered my pipboy while looking down a recon scope, and was able to fix it by using the recon scope again and unzooming normally. If not, you're stuck waiting for a patch or loading an earlier save.

Comment: I haven't had my vision go green, but I've had the screen get very blurry around the edges. I've been able to correct it on a few different occasions in two different ways: By entering then exiting power armor, or (strangely enough) causing a very large explosion nearby (e.g. shooting a car).

Comment: those methods can work, but are hit or miss and don't guarantee a fix, seems like it can be fixed if you trigger a "effect clear" action or similar, that's why doing an action that changes your view effects can help, but as i said, no guarantees and it can make it worse by doubling up :(